# How to find an ideal of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm fairly new to ideals in my algebra course, and I understand the basics of ideals, such that I is an ideal iff
(I,+) is a subgroup of (R,+) (using normal subgroup tests) and for all $r \in R$ and $a \in I$ then $ ar,ra \in I$.
As a question, I've been given a set and asked to list the ideals.

The set given is $\mathbb{Z}$/$20\mathbb{Z}$.
My first thought was to try and come up with an example or two; I came up with $I=$ { ${n\in \mathbb{Z}}||n|\geq0 $}; this seems like an ideal as it has the $0$ element, contains the additive property, and for any $r\in R$, $r n \in \mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$.

However this seems like a very plain and obvious example that I just 'made work.'  I'm not sure if there's a method or any way I should be going about finding these ideals. Any help would be great.

Edit:
I've found that all subgroups of a cyclic group are also cyclic of different sizes. The sizes are divisors of the size of the main group. Therefore in a cyclic group of size 20 there are 6 subgroups:

the original group,

{$0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18$} $=g^{10}$,

{$0,4,8,12,16$} $=g^5$,

{$0,5,10,15$} $=g^4$,

{$0,20$} $=g^2$,

{$0$} = $g^1$

Comment: Your $I$ is not even a subset of $\mathbb{Z} / 20 \mathbb{Z}$, let alone an ideal.

Comment: Do you know any theorems about orders of subgroups? Perhaps you can apply them in the context of rings?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic. Any ideal must be an additive subgroup (in addition to other conditions). What do you know about subgroups of cyclic groups?

Comment: The even numbers would be an example of an ideal in the integers.  You should be able to find something similar in $\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z_{20}$

Comment: @rogerl i believe that all subgroups of a cyclic group are also cyclic, who's order is a divisor of the size of the first cyclic group. Therefore since 20 has the divisors 1, 2, 4, 5, 10 then there's 5 subgroups of 20

Comment: You're forgetting one (how improper)!

Comment: @bounceback ah of course i'm forgetting the original group is also a subgroup so there's 6! thank you everyone

Comment: In general you are guaranteed cyclic subgroups of order any prime dividing the order of your group (this is Cauchy's Theorem). You are also guaranteed the existence of subgroups of maximal power of a prime dividing the order of the subgroup by Sylow.

Answer (score 2):

First you should remember that $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ is a set of equivalence classes; usually we choose the representatives $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,...,19\}$. So when you say all members from here $\ge 0$ you're essentially taking $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ to be an ideal of itself. And it turns out (rather obviously) that it's an ideal if you're not requiring that an ideal has to be a proper subset of the ring.

You can quickly check if $\{0\}$ is an ideal (it is, called the trivial ideal). For the other groups, to get familiar with ideals you might want to see what happens when you're testing whether or not $ra \in I$. Can you take anything from $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ and multiply it by anything in $g^{5}$ to get something not in $g^{5}$? These are the sorts of questions you want to ask.

Comment: Yeah i believe the difficulty i was having was finding the subgroups, now I've found them it's fairly easy to complete ideal tests on each group to check. Since they are cyclical groups, for $i \in I$ and $r \in R$ then $ir \in I$ as it is cyclical so z20 has 6 ideals